# Always align checkbox and text; Put some styles on it

Tags: html, css

I am using check box and text in the table's

```
<th>
```

Tag which is simply input and text, but I want that it always remain in the same line they do not stack each other in the next line.

**My html is -**

```
<th style="width: 17%">
  <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />    DisplayText
</th>
```

Ignore the width 17%, I put it there because I have 4 columns so I gave other more width.

I want to put some styles on the text that are:

```
 .listing-table table th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;}

.listing-table table th:first-letter {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold; }
```

How to put first letter style on it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .listing-table table th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
 }
.listing-table table th::first-letter {
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    color:red;
}
.listing-table table th input {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing-table">
    <table>
        <th style="width: 17%">DisplayText
         <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />    
        </th>
        <th style="width: 17%">
          <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />    DisplayText
        </th>
        <th style="width: 17%">
          <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />    DisplayText
        </th>
        <th style="width: 17%">
          <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />    DisplayText
        </th>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
.listing-table table th::first-letter {
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try with above code, may be your width is not enough to cater for one line.

note: first-letter pseudo, you have to have two colons(::) not one (:)

If you really wants to get label right after the checkbox, check this update.

Comment: it is not working it, i think it is considering input as the first not the text.

Comment: Can you try to put your text to <span> and change the css according to.

Answer (score 0):

`:first-letter` will  not working in your case. you need to add text before `check-box`.

see the below output.

```css
.listing-table table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.listing-table table th:first-letter {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing-table">
  <table>
    <th style="width: 17%">
      this
      <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />DisplayText
    </th>
    <th style="width: 17%">
      <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />DisplayText
    </th>
    <th style="width: 17%">
      <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />DisplayText
    </th>
    <th style="width: 17%">
      <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />DisplayText
    </th>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

You were missing `:` in `::first-letter` pseudo-element

```css
 .listing-table table th {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 .listing-table table th::first-letter {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="listing-table">
  <table>
    <th style="width: 17%">
      DisplayText
      <input type="checkbox" class="exc" onclick="somefunction()" />
    </th>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `::` is used for pseudo-elements and first-letter is a pseudo-element :) Edited the answer.